# Changing border-bottom to border-top

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I want to have a transistion on my menu list when hovered but I want to change the border-bottom to border-top.
How can I do this?

```css
  .sliding-middle-out {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
 transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <li class="scroll sliding-middle-out"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
```

Comment: You want the border to transition from the bottom to the top (vertically through the element, or simply a fade-out/fade-in)? Or you want to change which border is coloured/highlighted?

Comment: instead of using `:after` used `:before` http://jsbin.com/hivetigogu/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:before` pseudo element instead of the `:after` pseudo element so the line is displayed on top of (before) your link:

```css
.sliding-middle-out {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle-out:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
 transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:before {
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<li class="scroll sliding-middle-out"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
```

*Note that the line isn't made with the border property but with the background of the pseudo element*